# getElementsByTagName Returns zero not null why

Tags: java, xml, dom, nodes

```
NodeList myNodes = myDoc.getElementsByTagName("dne");
```

The element "dne" does not exist in myDoc.

- Yet, myNodes is not  **null**, why? If dne is not in myDoc, myNodes should be null.

What am I missing?

Comment: Why do you expect `null` to be returned instead of an empty `NodeList`?

Comment: I guess that behavior is similar in almost all languages/frameworks: function should return object, but doesn't find it --> null. function should return list but finds nothing --> empty list. Some languages/frameworks might offer a [Optional](https://www.baeldung.com/java-optional) funtionality

Answer (score 1):

> myNodes should be null.

Why?  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html#getElementsByTagName(java.lang.String)

> Returns: A list of matching Element nodes.

It doesn't say it returns null if the list is empty.  It simply returns an empty list.  If the length is 0, you know there were no matching nodes.